# NSFetchedResultsController delegate only triggers if the predicate is nil

Tags: iphone, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've been developing this App for a few months and we decided to implement Core Data on it.
I'm using Magical Record but this problem was already present before Magical Record.

The App loads a view that has the fetchedResultsController, while we are saving data in a background thread.

(NOT WORKING)

```
    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id_user = %@",[prefs valueForKey:@"userID"]];
fetchedResultsController = [ICCall MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:nil
               withPredicate:predicate
                    sortedBy:@"id_Chamada"
                   ascending:NO
                   inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];

return fetchedResultsController;}
```

(WORKING - notice predicate is set to nil)

```
    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id_user = %@",[prefs valueForKey:@"userID"]];
fetchedResultsController = [ICCall MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:nil
               withPredicate:nil
                    sortedBy:@"id_Chamada"
                   ascending:NO
                   inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];

return fetchedResultsController;}
```

In case you are wondering we insert data in a background thread calling this method:

```
    -(void)callWithID:(NSDictionary*)newCall{
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    ICCall *call = nil;

    call = [ICCall MR_findFirstWithPredicate:
            [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id_Chamada = %@",[newCall valueForKey:@"id_Chamada"] ]
                                   inContext:localContext];

    if(call)
    {
        // Call already Exists, update it?
    }
    else
    {
        call = [ICCall MR_createInContext:localContext ];
        call.id_Chamada = [newCall valueForKey:@"id_Chamada"];
        call.id_user = [newCall valueForKey:@"id_user"];
        call.designacao = [newCall valueForKey:@"designacao"];
        call.telefone = [newCall valueForKey:@"telefone"];
        call.data = [newCall valueForKey:@"data"];
        call.assunto = [newCall valueForKey:@"assunto"];
        call.mensagem = [newCall valueForKey:@"mensagem"];
        call.importancia = [newCall valueForKey:@"importancia"];
        call.ligar_volta = [newCall valueForKey:@"ligar_volta"];
        call.respondido = [newCall valueForKey:@"respondido"];
        call.respondido_data = [newCall valueForKey:@"respondido_data"];
        call.lido = [newCall valueForKey:@"lido"];
        call.eliminadoFO = [newCall valueForKey:@"eliminadoFO"];
        call.notas = [newCall valueForKey:@"notas"];
        call.favorito = [newCall valueForKey:@"favorito"];
        NSLog(@"--------------------------- CALL");
    }

} completion:^{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] save];
    }];
}];}
```

So if I set a predicate in the fetchedResultsController the fetchedResultsController delegate will not trigger when I am inserting information in the background,if no predicate is set all fetchedResultsController delegate methods trigger properly.

This problem has persisted since before the MagicalRecord wrapper, I even tried other wrappers but to no avail.
Have been trying to fix this since last week, running out of options...
A friend suggested me to not use threads but I really don't want to go that way.
Suggestions?

Comment: You debugged the user I'd of the stored objects and the value in prefs? Are they an exact match?

Comment: If I leave to the Home view or simply kill the App and execute it again the new records show... So all the values are correct...

Comment: So where is the delegate set on the FRC?

Comment: I set it in view did load where i initialize the FRC:                                                                     NSError *error;
 if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
  // Update to handle the error appropriately.
  NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  exit(-1);  // Fail
 }
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;